# .setChecked() isn't setting the state of radio button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm creating a security settings part in my app.

There are 3 radio buttons that allow the user to choose between a passcode, TouchID or nothing. All radio buttons are unchecked by default. When clicking on a radio button (e.g. to use passcode), the code checks to see if the user has set up a passcode. If the user hasn't, a dialog is shown and the radio button remains unchecked. The user then goes and sets up a passcode (setUpPasscode button).

Once set up, the passcode activity closes with the return case '2' and the radio button with the passcode option should be checked. It isn't however. When I re-launch the application, the button is checked though. It somehow isn't checked immediately after finishing the previous activity but it is technically checked. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class SecuritySettings extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView goBackToSettings;
    Button setUpPasscode;
    Button setUpTouchID;
    RadioButton usePasscodeSelection;
    RadioButton useTouchIDSelection;
    RadioButton useNeitherSelection;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Dialog myDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.security_settings);

        goBackToSettings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.closeSettingsButtonID);
        setUpPasscode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setUpPasscodeButtonID);
        setUpTouchID = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setUpTouchIDButtonID);
        usePasscodeSelection = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.usePasscode);
        useTouchIDSelection = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.useTouchID);
        useNeitherSelection = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.useNothing);

        myDialog = new Dialog(this);

        //load state of radio buttons
        loadRadioButtons();

        // go back to main settings page
        goBackToSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent goBackToMainSettings = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppSettings.class);
                goBackToMainSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(goBackToMainSettings);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //Open new activity for setting passcode
        setUpPasscode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent setUpPasscodeActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetupPasscode.class);
                startActivityForResult(setUpPasscodeActivity, 2);
            }
        });

        // Open new activity for setting up TouchID
        setUpTouchID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent setupTouchIDActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetupTouchID.class);
                startActivityForResult(setupTouchIDActivity, 1);
            }
        });

        // when clicked, all other buttons become unchecked and the state of the buttons are saved
        usePasscodeSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                boolean bCheckForPasscode = doesUserHavePasscode();

                // If true, user has a passcode setup
                if (bCheckForPasscode)
                {
                    usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(true);
                    useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(false);
                    useNeitherSelection.setChecked(false);
                    saveRadioButtons();
                }
                else
                {
                    //No passcode detected for user

                    // Load previous radio button configuration since the selection wasn't valid
                    loadRadioButtons();
                    NoOptionSetPopup(null, "You must set up a passcode to enable this option.");
                }

            }
        });

        useTouchIDSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                boolean bCheckForTouchID = doesUserHaveTouchIDSetup();

                // If true, user has TouchID setup
                if (bCheckForTouchID)
                {
                    usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(false);
                    useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(true);
                    useNeitherSelection.setChecked(false);
                    saveRadioButtons();
                }
                else
                {
                    //No passcode detected for user

                    // Load previous radio button configuration since the selection wasn't valid
                    loadRadioButtons();
                    NoOptionSetPopup(null, "You must set up TouchID to enable this option.");
                }

            }
        });

        useNeitherSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(false);
                useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(false);
                useNeitherSelection.setChecked(true);
                saveRadioButtons();
            }
        });

    }

    // Open sharedpreferences and get the value that was saved there after setting up passcode using the same key 'string'
    public boolean doesUserHavePasscode()
    {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        String checkHashString = sharedPreferences.getString("hashed_password", null);
        if (checkHashString == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Open sharedpreferences and get the value that was saved there after setting up TouchID using the same key 'string'
    public boolean doesUserHaveTouchIDSetup()
    {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        boolean bDoesUserHaveTouchIDSetup = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("doesUserHaveTouchIDSetup", false);
        return bDoesUserHaveTouchIDSetup;
    }

    public void NoOptionSetPopup(View v, String message)
    {
        TextView closePopup;
        TextView contents;
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.no_option_setup_popup);
        closePopup = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.closePopupButtonID);
        contents = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.theMessageID);
        contents.setText(message);

        closePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //Close popup
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.show();
    }

    // Callback method to get the boolean from SetupPasscode/SetupTouchID activity & override the method
    // What is being done here is that after a passcode/TouchID has been setup, we automatically assume that the newly set-up authentication will want to be used by the user.
    // The values being returned from the activities only happen when they're successfully done (passed all validation checks).
    // We then automatically make the corresponding radio button selected (if passcode setup, then select the 'use passcode on startup' radio button)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            // Case for returning from SetupPasscode class
            case 2:
                // fetch the boolean value
                boolean isDone = data.getBooleanExtra("isDone", false);

                usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(isDone);
                useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(false);
                useNeitherSelection.setChecked(false);
                saveRadioButtons();
                loadRadioButtons();
                break;
            // Case for returning from SetupTouchID class
            case 1:
                // fetch the boolean value
                boolean isTouchIDSetup = data.getBooleanExtra("isTouchIDDone", false);


                usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(false);
                useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(isTouchIDSetup);
                useNeitherSelection.setChecked(false);
                saveRadioButtons();
                loadRadioButtons();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void saveRadioButtons()
    {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("usePasscodeOption", usePasscodeSelection.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("useTouchIDOption", useTouchIDSelection.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("useNeitherOption", useNeitherSelection.isChecked());
    }

    public void loadRadioButtons()
    {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("usePasscodeOption", false));
        useTouchIDSelection.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("useTouchIDOption", false));
        useNeitherSelection.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("useNeitherOption", false));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to overload the **onResume** method and checking the state of your radio buttons as that will be the last control where the flow will leave your activity.

Comment: I've researched into the application life-cycle and tried getting it to work using onResume, onRestart and some other ways but I'm still having no luck. Any other potential solutions?

Comment: I would suggest wrapping these various similar functions into smaller ones for a better understanding. Wrap onClickListeners of all elements in setupListeners() functions and similarly for findViewByIds as well in its own function. Let me know after the edit.

Comment: I've noticed that through debugging, inside my 'onActivityResult' switch statement, the values are not being set correctly. The line "usePasscodeSelection.setChecked(isDone)" has a variable "isDone" which is true and then I've checked the state of the button using "String.valueof(usePasscodeSelection.isChecked()" and that gets returned as false. I think my problem might have something to do with this part...